# UIImagePickerController in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, video, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I am wanting to have my application display the video camera for my main controller. So far I have been able to use a controller that extends UIViewController and then through code instantiate a UIImagePickerController. Now I would like to see if there is a way to avoid creating a UIViewController and instead create the UIImagePickerController directly.

So far I have tried:

```
class VideoRecorderViewController: UIImagePickerController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.sourceType = .Camera
        self.cameraCaptureMode = .Video
        self.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
        self.allowsEditing = false
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.showsCameraControls = false
    }

    ...
}
```

I now get 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'cameraCaptureMode 1 not available because mediaTypes does contain public.movie

Does anyone have example of the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have imported the `MobileCoreServices` framework to make your video capturing work.

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

And just replace the below line of your code:

```
self.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, though this didn't quite work as presented. Turns out it is a sequence issue. Putting 'self.mediaTypes' first resolves the issue and in swift2 it appears to be [kUTTypeMovie as String]

Comment: BTW just been advised that it is not recommended to extend  UIImagePickerCobtroller, since it isn't designed to be extended.